# Something strange is happening on Form with Tabs; labels almost seem to be stacking

Tags: forms, ms-access, tabs, label, bold

I noticed "bold" text on a form that I had set to not be bold, so I opened in design mode, checked it, it was not bold but on screen it was...so I closed the form and reopened at first record and text looked fine...started going through the records and the got bolder and bolder with each new record...is this normal behavior? has any one else noticed it? could something I've done be causing it???

[image] top two lines are record one, bottom two are record 13

this seems to only be happening with that one line right above the tabs...

I haven't tried anything aside from resetting the text in design view...but it comes up normal on first record...

Comment: This is not a programming issue. Suggest you post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I have noted this too. I don't think it has to do with tabs, rather with the used font, and perhaps graphics driver. -- I learned to ignore it. :-)